# Console errors are not being shown

Tags: command-line, error-handling, pipe

The problem is no errors are being shown even when I type wrong command as shown.
There are several cases:

- `bash> blablabla`
- `bash> man blablabla`

The output of `lsof -a -p $$ -d0,1,2` gives the following:

```
zsh     3565 username    0u   CHR  136,2      0t0    5 /dev/pts/2 
zsh     3565 username    1u   CHR  136,2      0t0    5 /dev/pts/2
zsh     3565 username    2w   CHR    1,3      0t0 1029 /dev/null
```

I have managed to manually redirect commands output to console by prepending `2> /dev/pts/2` to each command, but still don't know how to make it global.

Comment: Could you update your question with `lsof -a -p $$ -d0,1,2` output? If output is empty try `lsof -a -p $$`

Comment: `lsof -a -p $$ -d0,1,2` outputs the following:

zsh     2986 aleksey    0u   CHR  136,3      0t0    6 /dev/pts/3|||
zsh     2986 aleksey    1u   CHR  136,3      0t0    6 /dev/pts/3|||
zsh     2986 aleksey    2w   CHR    1,3      0t0 1029 /dev/null|||

Comment: Please update your question, for better readability, it is difficult read command output in comment :)

Comment: Could you post .bashrc on http://pastebin.com/ ?

Comment: http://ideone.com/Q2hF3m

Comment: As you can see standard error is redirect on /dev/null, I guess there is `2> /dev/null` in your file running at shell login. As I can see you are using `zsh` that  don't know. Is there file like .bashrc for bash that run at user login?

Comment: @Letizia `.zshrc` (and `.zprofile`, if the exist).

Comment: Okey, thanks, try to check if there are some redirection and post these file, so I can look with you. It can depend on errors in such file.

Comment: @Letizia config files don't contain redirections, though the output always goes to `/dev/null` regardless of shell(bash, zsh, fish). This sentence `exec 2>/dev/pts/2` fixes the problem across all shells at the same time when executed. 
However, after system restart, output again is set to `null`.

Comment: Yes, I know. You can use @muru answer as workaroud and put command at the end of your .zshrc. I guess that there is an error in some file executed during login shell. Did you check /etc/profile?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `exec` command which is used for shell-level redirection in `bash` also works in `zsh`. Try:

```
exec 2>/dev/pts/2
```

Comment: Thanks for good proposal. However, this only works until the system is restarted.